# Finding a CDF from a PDF (question about the bounds)

Tags: probability-distributions

I am doing a problem from my textbook, and I have a question about how they write the answer. The problem is the following

If 
$\begin{align*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 3(1-x)^2, 0 < x < 1\\
 0, \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$

find the cdf $F(x)$. First, I integrated to find that $F(x) = C-(1-x)^3$. I know that $1 = F(1) = C-(1-1)^3$ which means that $C=1$. Thus, I write my answer as

$\begin{align*}
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0, x \leq 0\\
 1-(1-x)^3, 0 < x < 1\\
 1, x \geq 1\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$

However, the book's answer has different bounds. They write

$\begin{align*}
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0, x < 0\\
 1-(1-x)^3, 0 \leq x < 1\\
 1, x \geq 1\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$

Can anyone explain why they include $0$ on the second case? Since it is a continuous PDF, is it ireelevant? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. You can include equality in either of the first two cases. However, note that the last value of the CDF should be $1$ for $x\geq 1$, and not $0$ as you have written. A CDF is always non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first in last case of $F(x)$, that $x \geqslant 1$, you should write $F(x)=1$ instead of $0$!

But about your question, since CDF is right continuous function by definition, you should write bounds as $m \leqslant x < M$ except of $m \longmapsto -\infty$.

Comment: oops, that $0$ was a typo. Don't you mean right-continuous, though?

Comment: @mXdX Yes, I edit my answer.